# Android blank screen in "preview" screen

Tags: android, windows, android-virtual-device

So I have a problem with android virtual device. Today, I was just making an some app (i just need it at case of my course) I tried to run it on my telephone,when i was installing it,I've get some notification that I've just install clicked,I don't know exactly what was it about,but I remember,it was something about download newest api to run it on my device. When I downloaded everything was fine,but when I was about to continue my course and make another app, I noticed that my "preview" screen (I mean this screen of virtual device where we can see how our xml will look like) it's blank,I've added some stuff like buttons etc. But it didn't show up in screen, so I've made another project,but problem is still same. what should I do?

Comment: What version you are using of support, design library etc.

Comment: Basically,i've used an "Android API 28" - that's all. I don't have any external libraries etc. It's my very begining in android. :)

Comment: If your gradle compiles beta dependencies. Please use 27.1.1 because i have that problem too i was using 28.0.0beta3 and when i decreased it to 27.1.1 it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this dependencies in your app level build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```